# How to merge n lists together item by item for each list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make one large list for entering into a database with values from 4 different lists. I want it to be like

```
[[list1[0], list2[0], list3[0], list4[0]], [list1[1], list2[1], list3[1], list4[1]], etc.....]
```

Another issue is that currently the data is received like this:

```
[ [ [list1[0], list1[1], [list1[3]]], [[list2[0]]], etc.....]
```

I've tried looping through each list using indexs and adding them to a new list based on those but it hasn't worked, I'm pretty sure it didn't work because some of the lists are different lengths (they're not meant to be but it's automated data so sometimes there's a mistake).

Anyone know what's the best way to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Create a list and extend it with all your sub lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First list can be constructed using zip function as follows (for 4 lists):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7,8]
list3 = [9,10,11,12]
list4 = [13,14,15,16]

res = list(zip(list1,list2,list3,list4))
```

For arbitrtary number of lists stored in another list u can use *-notation to unpack outer list:

```
lists = [...]

res = list(zip(*lists))
```

To construct list of lists for zipping from you data in second issue use flatten concept to it and then zip:

```
def flatten(l):
    res = []
    for el in l:
        if(isinstance(el, list)):
            res += flatten(el)
        else:
            res.append(el)

    return res

auto_data = [...]

res = list(zip(*[flatten(el) for el in auto_data]))
```

Some clarification at the end:

zip function construct results of the smallest length between all inputs, then you need to extend data in list comprehension in last code string to be one length to not lose some info.

Answer (score 0):

If the **flatten** concept doesn't work, try this out:

```
import numpy as np

myArray = np.array([[list1[0], list2[0], list3[0], list4[0]], [list1[1], list2[1], list3[1], list4[1]]])
np.hstack(myArray)
```

Also that one should work:

```
np.concatenate(myArray, axis=1)
```

---

Just for those who will search for the solution of this problem when lists are of the same length:

```
def flatten(lists):
    results = []
    for numbers in lists:
        for output in numbers:
            results.append(output)
            return results

print(flatten(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, this is your input:

```
l = [[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4],[2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4],[3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4],[4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4]]
```

and you would like to have this output

```
[[1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1],...]
```

If so, this could be done by using `zip`

```
zip(*l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a for loop which only gives you the counter variable. Use that variable to index the lists. Make a temporary list , fill it up with the values from the other lists. Add that list to the final one. With this you will et the desired structure.

```
nestedlist = []
for counter in range(0,x):
    temporarylist = []
    temporarylist.append(firstlist[counter])
    temporarylist.append(secondlist[counter])
    temporarylist.append(thirdlist[counter])
    temporarylist.append(fourthlist[counter])
    nestedlist.append(temporarylist)
```

If all the 4 lists are the same length you can use this code to make it even nicer.

```
nestedlist = []
for counter in range(0,len(firstlist)):    #changed line
    temporarylist = []
    temporarylist.append(firstlist[counter])
    temporarylist.append(secondlist[counter])
    temporarylist.append(thirdlist[counter])
    temporarylist.append(fourthlist[counter])
    nestedlist.append(temporarylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

This comprehension should work, with a little help from `zip`:

```
mylist = [i for i in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)]
```

But this assumes all the list are of the same length. If that's not the case (or you're not sure of that), you can "pad" them first, to be of same length.

```
def padlist(some_list, desired_length, pad_with):
    while len(some_list) < desired_length:
        some_list.append(pad_with)
    return some_list

list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]
maxlength = len(max(list_of_lists, key=len))
list_of_lists = [padlist(l, maxlength, 0) for l in list_of_lists]
```

And now do the above comprehension statement, works well in my testing of it

```
mylist = [i for i in zip(*list_of_lists)]
```